# ios UITabBarcontroller custom , How can I achieve the following tabbar architect

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

[iPad custom tabbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNrVB.png)        [iPhone custom tabbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK8uv.png)

iPhone => How to add that dotted  : button in tabbar, which opens more options 
 iPad => How to add tabbar buttons to left of the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be totally custom. I would use `UIStackView` and change its `direction` to `.horizontal` on iPhones, and to `.vertical` on iPad.

The dots is just a button with image you can add to the stackView.

Comment: Thanks Tal , can you please give me any sample code